# Prolog Nested Query

Tags: python, prolog

I am calling one Prolog function which returns a list. I traverse the list using a Python loop and do somethings. In the same loop, when I catch a specific condition, I call another Prolog function. I tried to execute this code with a single prolog object but got

> "pyswip.prolog.NestedQueryError: The last query was not closed"

error.
Later, I decided to use a second prolog variable for inner queries. Even, having two totally independent prolog objects (each having its own assertions and consultation calls), I am still getting the same error. Can somebody show me how to achieve this?

Many thanks,
Ferda

Comment: I don't use Python with Prolog but am interested in this question. I found [Multi-threading when using swi prolog as embedded engine](https://discourse.swi-prolog.org/t/multi-threading-when-using-swi-prolog-as-embeded-engine/2085) which was answered by Jan W. the creator and maintainer of SWI-Prolog so the problem is not with SWI-Prolog.

Comment: Have you looked as some [pyswip test cases](https://github.com/yuce/pyswip/blob/master/tests/test_examples.py)?

Comment: Hi, @Guy Coder thanks for the comments. I checked the link yesterday evening, I also commented some lines on the code where it throws nested_query ex. However, I think those lines were not the correct ones cause I still get some error. I do not know what is pyswip test cases. I will also check that link now. I will write back later..

Comment: This is also posted on [SWI-Prolog forum](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/nested-query/4098/2)

Comment: Yes I posted :) I changed python code to have a quick fix. I am using a temp list and traversing that temp list instead of traversing the query results directly.

Answer (score 0):

I used two prolog instances with two separate pl files. I initiated both. For the outer queries I used the first one and for the inner queries I used the second one.
This resolved the problem.
Later, for another reason (error calling the prolog from web interface) I started to use PrologMQI  which I believe handles multi threated requests better.